# How do I change the styles of the input container

Tags: javascript, css, sass, react-select

I've gone through the docs and I can't seem to find any way of changing this input container styles.

I can change the input react-select__input styles, but the parent is just unreachable unless I use this specific class name.

The only other way is to use the `value-container > div:last-child`
But that's just a bad idea no for this scenario is I change the components occasionally.

I'd love the use that class name `css-15n6m` but it changes with every version of the package from my experience so far

[image]

Comment: you may try overriding the styles of the input itself. like `react-select__input` in your case.

Comment: This won't work in this case since I can't delete the padding that is placed on the container and the input itself is already quite small

Comment: Could you provide some code you did ?

Answer (score 0):

React-Select uses EmotionJs for styling, and it is possible to pass in override styles for any internal component. Say, for instance, I wanted to override the base styling of the Menu control. I could provide a method for that:

```
const menuStyles = (base, state) => {
  const { menuIsOpen } = state.selectProps;
  let addons = {
    border: '1px solid #ccc',
    zIndex: 1000,
    marginTop: 0
  };
  if (menuIsOpen) {
    addons = Object.assign(addons, {
      borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
      borderTopRightRadius: 0,
      borderTop: 0,
      boxShadow: '0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15)'
    });
  }
  return Object.assign(base, addons);
};

// ...
<Select styles={{menu: menuStyles}} />
```

It requires playing around a little to truly figure it all out, but there is a [pretty good topic in the documentation](https://react-select.com/styles).

**Note:** The kicker is, trying to figure out which `Component` is the component you truly want to style. The `Input` component isn't an HTML input. The only one used with React-Select is a hidden control. Most likely you're trying to style one of the many Container elements that make up the visible control, such as the `SelectContainer`, the `ValueContainer` or maybe the `MultiValueContainer`. Like I said, you have to play a little, but you *can* do it. There's good [documentation around the Components in the documentation](https://react-select.com/components) as well.

Comment: using this method is completely acceptable and in most cases it will work.
but specifically speaking of the input container there is just no way of addressing it.

playing with the input style will declare styles for ```react-select__input``` but not for the container div ```css-15n6m```.

Comment: You know, you're right. The React-Select `Input` is not what you would expect. I will amend my answer.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly are you trying to style? Background? Margins? Width? Height?

Can you provide an example of what are you trying to achieve?

Also, you can add css directly to the tag, example:

```
<div style="width:10px;height:20px;background-color:#b10000;"></div>
```

But without referring to the class or id you will not be able to **individually** change the style of a tag (element).

Comment: I'm trying to reset the margin and the padding,
and since react-select is creating their own input container (div)
I'm unable to apply those inline styles

Comment: This would only change the styling of a container possibly holding a React-Select element, not the element itself.